# Perl cpanm failing to install modules due to lack of usr/local/man/man3 write permission

Tags: perl, cpanm

I'm using `cpanm` and local::lib to install modules on a Pair.com Ubuntu VPS box.  Shell access but no root access.  The modules are going to ~/perl5.  The installed Perl is 5.10.1.

Install of both `Module::Build::Tiny` and `Class::Method::Modifiers` failed.  Looking at the build.log, you can see that the tests ran fine, but the install failed with the message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/man/man3'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/man/man3'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The install failed, and using `cpanm --force` does not help.  I don't need these modules to put anything in man3.  I've installed lots of other modules today, and they didn't care about man3.

Is there a way I can get around this?  I don't need any man pages created for modules.

Edit: I am using local::lib.  Here are the relevant environment variables (I think).  Sort of new ground for me here...

```
PERL5LIB=/usr/home/wruppertvps/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/usr/home/wruppertvps/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/usr/home/wruppertvps/perl5"
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/usr/home/wruppertvps/perl5
MANPATH=:/usr/home/wruppertvps/perl5/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man
```

Comment: How are you specifying install location? Is it via `local::lib`? If so, please show the relevant environment variables, they will control where different elements get installed.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I am using local::lib.  I have added some env vars to the question.

Comment: can't reproduce here with cpanm 1.5007. I get installation to `$LOCAL-LIB-DIR/man/man3` as you would expect. I don't have `$MANPATH` defined but if I do so then it makes no difference. `Module::Build::Tiny` seems to call `ExtUtils::Install` for the actual installation copying and that seems to rely on a config setting called `installman3dir`. The problem must logically be somewhere around there.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thanks, just figured that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem was in ExtUtils::Install.  I guess it doesn't see local::lib.  Setting PERL_INSTALL_ROOT fixed the problem.

`PERL_INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/home/wruppertvps/perl5`